# How to start the camera on click of listview item button in listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-camera

Summery of problem:- I have classes named AttachPicture which extends the ListActivity and another class MyArrayAdapter which extends the ArrayAdapter.With the help of these classes i am able to create a ListView in which i have two textviews and a button in each item.ListView is working fine no problem till here.But now i want to start the camera on click of button presents in every item of listview, here's my problem starts give me any idea and explain it with code to get the expected result.

Here's my code which i m putting inside the

```
onClick(){
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

}
```

But eclipse is not allowing my app to put startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); I dont know why it is happening.Help me to get rid of this problem.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that eclipse won't build/compile the project? What error (if any) is it giving? A clean sometimes helps.

Comment: Shailendra rajawat's answer solved my problem....Thanx for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write `button.onClickListener()`
{
//code for camera intent
}
inside `getView()` overridden method of Adapter;

in case arrayAdapter does not provide getView(view, position , ... ) extend base Adapter .

**Editing**

`startActivtyForResult()` is method of activity class , so pass Activity context to Adpter , then call `context.startActivtyForResult()`